# C# void property

Tags: c#, properties, void

I began object-oriented programming in C# and I am very inquisitive by properties. I would like to compile an automatic property of `void` type like this :

```
void Empty { get; set; }
```

My teacher got exhausted when I showed him I found how to use read-writable property in C#, but it's not compilable. Do you have any idea ?

When it will work, I will to replace something like :

```
void main() { return; }
```

by

```
void main()
 {
    this.Empty = () => { return; };
    return this.Empty;
 }
```

Did somebody on the planete has already thought about it ? Or am I the weirdest programmer on the Earth ?

Thank you.

Comment: Furthermore, why would you want to replace a single keyword ('return') with a property assignment, a lambda expression, *and* a return? Yes, quite weird :)

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: _"My teacher got exhausted when I showed him I found how to use read-writable property in C#, but it's not compilable. Do you have any idea ?"_ What exactly means _"exhausted"_ here? But I can well imagine :-P ...

Comment: I just want to do that for fun ! Like if I am with another programmer, I could say : << Do you want to see something fun ? >> I know it is useless. But I want to be of the people who managed doing this.

Comment: Doing what?  I don't understand what is "fun" here.  It just doesn't make any sense. Even if your property were properly typed (`Action`?) it would just be a property that returns a method which... doesn't do anything.

Comment: There is in fact a use case for this, but it's obscure and related to authoring compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from your code sample, you are probably looking for the Action type

```
Action Empty { get; set; }
```

Then you will be able to use:

```
this.Empty = () => { some code here }
```

Comment: Thank you ! That's exactly what I was searching ! Plus, you got me able to perform functional programming in C# according to what I read, Action would be like `let _` in F# or Ocaml.

Answer (score 2):

`void` designates NO type/value!

What should a `void` property actually return or receive?

It absolutely makes no sense to even ask about.

---

The closest thing I could think of in c++, is to have overloaded `void` function versions depending on the instance reference constness on calling

```
 void foo();
 void foo() const;
```

Though I'm not that well versed with C#, to tell cases where this could make sense.

Comment: @SonerGönül In this case it's an answer IMHO.

Comment: @EdS. Yes, I was afraid so. It doesn't really make sense in c++ either.

Comment: In C++ it does.  If you're calling `foo()` on a `const` object then you have to provide the `const` overload.  This often makes sense, just depends on what `foo` does.

Comment: @EdS. I'm having a hard time to think about reasonable use cases though.

Comment: `std::map::operator[]` is one.  Really it's most often useful when returning a pointer or reference to a member.

Comment: @EdS. _"`std::map::operator[]` is one."_ Ehhmm, are we still talking about `void` return types?!?

Comment: ...I suppose that's a fair point :).  Yeah... I can't think of a use case either.